# if / else / else if statements, a matter of function or style?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am comparing data that can have only 3 possible results, less than, greater than, or equal to.

Hence the last statement could be an else or an else / if, and the block would behave the same:

```
  if(iter.data === data) {
    return iter;
  } else if(data < iter.data) {
    iter = iter.left;

  // else or else if will suffice here
  } else if(data > iter.data) {
    iter = iter.right;
  }
```

Is there any functional difference I am missing, or is this simply a matter of style?

Is there a good style reference, that covers this if it is only a matter of style?

Comment: when switching an assignment, I prefer ternary expressions. Some say to avoid elseif as it can be harder to read, especially when nested, but to be sure, all the ways of coding such logic are valid and it comes down to preference of the coder or organization.

Comment: You can skip the last comparison. Just type "esle" or return last value. it will interrupt the function anyway. In this case it's only style issue.

Comment: @Hoxz not *necessarily*. Consider `data` being `undefined` and `iter.data` not. Then neither of these conditions will match. Same thing would happen if either `data` or `iter.data` is `NaN`. If both are non-NaN (and also probably finite) numbers, then the conditions are exhaustive. But in a more general case, there are more options.

Comment: @VLAZ In your example we already have more then 3 states. I don't think that was meant. But good point.

Comment: Bobby, can you [edit] to specify whether any the values being compared in your question can be `undefined` or `NaN`?

Comment: We need more information to answer this. Specifically, why is the first branch returning `iter` but the other branches are not? Is there a return after the first branch and what is its context?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler/interpreter won't care and will optimize these regardless, but from a mental load standpoint `else if` implies another comparison, whereas `else` implies a "fall-through" and most codebases will prefer the latter.

As an added bonus, the fall-through also ensures that one of the branches is *always* taken. Generally speaking, *no branches* being taken at all could potentially lead to much weirder bugs than the *wrong* branch being taken.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let me add:

```
switch (true){
  case iter.data === data: return iter;
  case iter.data > data: iter = iter.left; break;
  case iter.data < data: iter = iter.right; break;
}
```

With the example, I probably would do this though:

```js
if (iter.data === data) {
  return iter;
}
iter = (iter.data > data) ? iter.left : iter.right;
```

It highlights the different behavior between the branches (return vs assignment), which for me is the most important thing to recognize. And it even has the least lines of code.

But yes, it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score -2):

Would something like this work? check for less and greater but returns the default if both fail.

```
//if/else
if(data < iter.data) {
    return iter.left;
}
if(data > iter.data) {
    return iter.right;
}
return iter;
```

DanDavis suggested ternary so maybe this?

```
//ternary example
return data < iter.data ? iter.left : (data > iter.data ? iter.right : iter);
```